# Discrepancy between Stack Overflow data dump and live data query

Tags: support, data-explorer, data-dump

When [querying the live data using Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/342438/441903/count-of-unanswered-and-unclosed-android-tagged-questions-between-2014-01-01-and#graph) for a weekly count of unanswered, unclosed questions tagged with android, there seems to be a large discrepancy between these results and those using the March 16th data dump from the [archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange).

Using Data Explorer with the above query, we see the following graph:
[image: Data Explorer graph]

Using the archive data (as imported to a local PostgreSQL database) with the query:

```
select extract(week from creationdate), count(*) 
    from posts q 
where 
    not exists (select * from posts a where a.parentid = q.id) 
    and q.creationdate >= '2014-01-01' 
    and q.creationdate < '2015-01-01' 
    and q.closeddate is null
    and q.parentid is null
    and q.tags like '%<android>%'
group by extract(week from creationdate)
```

we see:
[image: Local March 16 data dump graph]

Slight deviations between the two data sources are absolutely expected due to the dynamic nature of Stack Overflow (questions deleted, answered later on, closed, *etc*). However, it seems unlikely that such a large discrepancy between the two data sources would exist especially since the large spike in unanswered questions appears in both data sets, but at different times.

My questions are:

1. Can another user with a locally imported Stack Overflow March 16th data dump confirm this phenomenon to rule out the possibility of an error on my side (which is absolutely possible)?
2. Was there some type of systematic change in Stack Overflow that could have caused this discrepancy between data sets?

Comment: Tangential: `not exists (select * from Posts a where a.ParentId = q.Id)` is equivalent to `q.AnswerCount = 0`, and the latter ought to be faster.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is the culprit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community). The bot deletes zero-score unanswered questions (with fewer than 2 comments) after 365 days. The spike that you observe is not a spike in questions posted, but a reverted wave of questions *deleted*. In the March snapshot, this wave of deletion is in March 2014 (around week 10). In the current snapshot, it is in July 2014.

Removal of abandoned questions after 365 days [is the 3rd most common deletion reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/296609) on Stack Overflow, trailing only the deletion of questions and answers by their authors.

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much! This has been bugging me all day as I'm attempting to do analysis on this particular class of questions. It seems now that this analysis may now be limited to questions prior to March 2014 (around week 10).